# find if the date containd a valid format using a preg_match

Tags: php

I have 1 text input box so user can enter a date in the following format (i don’t want to use 3 separate input boxes for the month, date and year) :

```
mm/dd/yyyy (could be a single digit m/d/yyyy)
```

or

```
mm-dd-yyyy (single digit m-d-yyyy)
```

I then want to use preg_match to check if the user entered a value according to the format above. If yes, i will extract the month, day and year (using substr) and use php function checkdate() to check for a valid date, know when it’s a leap year and prevent mistakes such as September 31...

Hopefully, i’m not missing anything...

Right now, im stuck in trying to figure out how to use preg_match to check if the user has entered a valid date according to the format indicated above

this is what i’ve came up with... ???

```
preg_match(d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})
```

extracting the month , day and year (looks ok to me):

```
$date = trim($_POST['date']);
$month = substr($date, 0, 2);
$day = substr($date, 3, 2);
$year = substr($date, 6, 4);
```

and finally , check the date is valid (looks ok to me):

```
checkdate($month, $day, $year);
```

Thanks

Comment: Any reason to use regexps if you already have `checkdate`?

Comment: ok, so i don't need regexps... what if the user enters 2/2/1974 how do i extract the month, day and year ?

Comment: and if the user inputs using the symbol - like 2-2-1978? how do i first define what symbol did the user has use ?

Comment: replace `-` with `/` with `str_replace` then

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
if (preg_match("#^(\d{1,2})\D(\d{1,2})\D(\d{2,4})$", trim($date), $match)
        and checkdate($match[2], $match[1], $match[3])) {
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $match[2], $match[1], $match[3]);
    echo "Date is valid";
} else
    echo "Invalid date";
```

The only issue I see here is if user inputs something like 06.01.12 expecting your system to guess 2012, when `checkdate` will think of the year 12. You can't just add "20" at the start of the string, since another user may input something like 15.11.99 expecting a 1999 guess. This could be solved by a readonly field with javascript-based calendar, which will force correct date format, which you can then simply `explode("-", $date)` without using regexp.